# Упростить Promise Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Есть код, он рабочий. Я новичок в промисах, можно ли как-то упростить его? Знаю, что сделал неправильно, второй промис можно как-то вынести отдельно. Подскажите, как правильно сделать. Спасибо.

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

var App = require('./app.class');
var App = new App();


App.clientsList().then(async function (res) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(res.content);

    for(var k = 0; k<=$(".clientTable tr").length; k++) {

        var el = $(".clientTable tr").eq(k);
        var data = {
            fields: {
                "UF_CRM_1575291282905": $(el).find("td").eq(1).text(),
                "NAME": $(el).find("td").eq(6).text(),
                "SECOND_NAME": "Не указана",
                "UF_CRM_1575292481": $(el).find("td").eq(3).text().trim(),
                "PHONE": [{"VALUE": $(el).find("td").eq(8).text().trim(), "VALUE_TYPE": "WORK"}],
                "EMAIL": [{"VALUE": $(el).find("td").eq(4).find("a").text(), "VALUE_TYPE": "WORK"}]
            }
        };
        if (data.fields["UF_CRM_1575291282905"] == "" || data.fields["NAME"] == "") continue;





        var data_purchase = {
            page: "orders",
            mas_status: {
                "40226": "40226"
            },
            allorders: "",
            filter_contractor: data.fields["UF_CRM_1575291282905"],
            relativeDateRange: "thisYear",
            get_report: "1"
        };

        await App.getPurchase(data_purchase).then(purchase => {

            var $ = cheerio.load(purchase);
            var allPrice = 0.00;
            $(".ordProcc tbody tr").each(function (i, e) {
                var price = parseFloat($(e).find("td").eq(7).text().trim().replace(",", ".").replace(" ", ""));
                if (!isNaN(price)) {
                    allPrice += price;
                }
            });
            data.fields["UF_CRM_1575295352"] = allPrice.toFixed(2);
            console.log(data.fields["UF_CRM_1575291282905"]+":"+data.fields["UF_CRM_1575295352"]);

            // App.bxClientAdd(data);
        });








    }

});
```

Comment: await как раз нужен чтобы then убрать: `var purchase = await App.getPurchase(data_purchase)`

Answer (score 1):

Механики `Promise` и `async - await` хоть и разные, но используются для одной
и той же цели - упростить работу с асинхронным кодом и избежать `callback-hell`'а.

В Вашем случае вы пытаетесь использовать один механизм внутри другого.
Анонимную функцию из `App.clientsList().then()` не нужно указывать с ключевым
словом `async` (как соответственно и параметры внутри неё с `await`), 
потому что `Promise` сам по себе уже подразумевает обработку асинхронных данных.

Функция обработчика данных внутри `then()` выполнится, когда `Promise` разрешится положительно,то есть данные успешно придут и все дальнейшие манипуляции с ними вы будете выполнять внутри функции обработчика, но только когда `Promise` будет в состоянии `resolve`.
Метод `then()` также возвращает `Promise`, данные из которого при его `resolve` можно обработать в уже его `then()`.

Вы можете поместить второй `Promise`, `App.getPurchase(data_purchase).then()`, в функцию обработчика без `await`, а можете вернуть из этой функции необходимые данные и обработать их другой функцией в следующем `then()`, создав таким образом цепочку из `then()`:

```
 Promise.then(функция обработчика данных, 
    полученных, когда Promise станет resolve)
    .then(функция обработчика данных из предыдущего then())
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

`catch()` на случай, если один из `Promise` в цепочке не выполнится и перейдёт в состояние `reject`.